# Assigning arraycollection in component as dataprovider for datagrid in main app

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6, advanceddatagrid, arraycollection

Hi I have a simple (I think) question. I have the following custom component in Flex 4.6 (partial code).

```
<fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <s:ArrayCollection id="acItems"/>
        <s:ArrayCollection id="acOrder" source="{orderItems.source}"/>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>     
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            public var orderItems:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

            private function addToOrder():void
            {
                orderItems.addItem(itemGrid.selectedItem);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="itemGrid" dataProvider="{acItems}" width="100%" height="100%" borderVisible="false" click="addToOrder()">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn width="200" dataField="omschrijving" headerText="omschrijving"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="prijs" headerText="prijs"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

So whenever I click on an item, this gets added to an arraycollection.

Now I make a call to this component in my main application. It gets filled with data from a database. This is all working fine so I dont think the code is required to solve my problem :)

```
<components:Items acItems="{acItems}"/>
```

And next to this component, I have another datagrid in my main application. This one should get filled with the arraycollection I made in the custom component. But I have no singe idea how to assign this arraycollection as the dataprovider for the datagrid. Somebody with an idea?

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way would be injecting one ArrayCollection in both views. If you'd use a MVC framework like RobotLegs, those design principles would be enforced by the framework (unless you don't use in a wrong way).

Actually i would recommend learning about MVC and don't just rely on the simplified samples from Adobe.